# SQLite3 on iPhone - insert returns error code 8 attempt to write a readonly database

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite, insert, readonly

So, I have been beating my head against the wall on this for about a week now.

I'm writing an iPhone app that has an sqlite database in it. I'm able to open the database and read from it (I put some test data in there through via the command line / terminal), select specific data, etc. But, what I cannot do is insert into the database from the phone. When I execute sqlite3_exec(...) it returns error code 8 "attempt to write a readonly database."

I had read other questions on here saying that I was using the Main Bundle's database and not the users database, and that the simulator will often times just "let you do it" while on a live device you'll get an error. Well, that's not what's happening in my case - I'm getting this error while running on the simulator. And from what I can tell my code to check the database is exactly as a lot of others recommend it to be.

Here is the code I use to verify the database exists, and if it doesn't I copy it:

```
// initialize db (if not already)
+(void) checkDatabase {
    // setup some variables
    Boolean success;
    dbName = @"daarma.sqlite";
    NSArray *documentPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDirectory, YES);
    // I have tried this with both NSUserDirectory and NSUserDomainMask, desn't seem to make a difference
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPath objectAtIndex:0];
    dbPath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:dbName];
    //    dbPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"daarma" ofType:@"sqlite"];

    // check to see if the database already exists
    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    success = [fm fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
    if(success) {
        NSLog(@"Database exists, returning.");
        return;
    }

    // if not, we create it
    NSLog(@"Creating database in user profile...");
    NSString *dbPathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:dbName];
    [fm copyItemAtPath:dbPathFromApp toPath:dbPath error:nil];    

    [fm release];
    [documentPath release];
    [documentsDir release];
}
```

When I go to insert data using this:

```
sqlite3 *db;
int open = sqlite3_open_v2([dbPath UTF8String], &db, -1, NULL);
if(open == 0) {
    NSLog(@"open, inserting");
    NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into affiliates values('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12')"];
    int exec = sqlite3_exec(db, [sql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, NULL);
    NSLog(@"exec = %d",exec);
}
sqlite3_close(db);
```

exec returns with the above mentioned error code 8: ""attempt to write a readonly database."

I've also tried the usual restarts, cleaning the project, resetting the simulator data. I even went in to my Simulator directory and deleted all the application data out manually. When I tried to go back in, it recognized the database wasn't there and copied it over, but I still get that error.

EDIT:

I've just noticed that if I do this in the checkDatabase method:

```
NSError *error;
[fm copyItemAtPath:dbPathFromApp toPath:dbPath error:&error]; 
NSLog(@"error = %@",error);
```

it causes the simulator to crash the first go around (after doing a content reset), but each time after that it resumes the above error with no crashes. So maybe I am doing something wrong with my checkDatabase method. ?? :( It never tells me the output of the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code, and it failed with open = 21 (SQLITE_MISUSE) in the following line:

```
int open = sqlite3_open_v2([dbPath UTF8String], &db, -1, NULL);
```

Because you pass -1 to flags parameter.  It should be SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE.

I have some more comments.

```
[fm release];
[documentPath release];
[documentsDir release];
```

These release's are not necessary, because you don't alloc/init, retain, or copy them.

```
NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into affiliates values('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12')"];
int exec = sqlite3_exec(db, [sql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

You should use sqlite3_prepare_v2 and bind parameters instead of stringWithFormat: for SQL.

```
if(open == 0) { ... }
```

Whenever possible, you should use symbolic constant (SQLITE_OK) instead of magic number (0).

```
NSError *error;
[fm copyItemAtPath:dbPathFromApp toPath:dbPath error:&error]; 
NSLog(@"error = %@",error);
```

You should initialize error = nil before calling copyItemAtPath: because error is not changed when the copy operation succeeds.

Comment: The joys of learning Objective-c /sarcasm. thank you very much for your input! I will test those and return after to comment or mark answered.

Answer (score 2):

try to change the open function to this

```
sqlite3_open_v2([dbPath UTF8String], &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE , NULL);
```

or basically use the trivial open function

```
Sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String],&db);// this should do the job
```

hope that helps :)